# How to bind event to checkbox with knowing a part of its ID via jQuery

Tags: jquery

There is a

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="option2" id="checkbox_3" value="3" />
```

I tried this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id*="checkbox_"]').click(function () {
            alert('!!!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

but no success.

Any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/JAamg/

Comment: Are you sure you have included jQuery library before this script tag?
Please recheck... This is s correct code and it should work. :)

Comment: You should really consider using a common `class` for all those elements and then select it using `$('input.whateverClassYouChose')` - this will be **much** faster in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have not included jQuery.

Put this before (and outside of) your script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have got included jQuery. Others things of JQuery are working fine.

Comment: also have you include the js file in which this code is written?
Please check... Its working like charm on my end... :)